# Continuum cannot be written as Countable Union of Disjoint Closed Subsets

Tags: general-topology, compactness, connectedness, separation-axioms, continuum-theory

**Continuum:** $X$ is a continuum if it is a compact connected Hausdorff space.

> A continuum $X$ cannot be equal to $\bigcup\limits_{n=1}^\infty F_n$ for any $\{F_n\}$, where $\{F_n\}$ is a collection of disjoint nonempty closed subsets of $X$.
>
> **Hint:** Let $X = \bigcup\limits_{n=1}^\infty F_n$, and  $U_1$ be open set containing $F_2$ such that $\overline U_1 \cap F_1 = \varnothing$.  
> Let $X_1$ be a component of $\overline U_1$ meeting $F_2$. Then $X_1 \cap F_1 = \varnothing$ , and $X_1$ meets some $F_{n_2}, n_2>2$. 
> Let $U_2$ be open set containing $F_{n_2}$ such that $\overline U_2 \cap F_2 = \varnothing$, and let $X_2$ be a component of $\overline U_2\cap X_1$ meeting $F_{n_2}$. 
> Continuing, show that $X_1\supseteq X_2\supseteq X_3\supseteq\cdots$, but $\bigcap X_n = \varnothing$, obtaining a contradiction.

I was able to show that the sequence $(X_n)$ is a decreasing sequence of continua.  However, I haven't been able to show that $\bigcap X_n = \varnothing$. Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that in your construction,

$$ X_n \cap F_n = \varnothing.$$

Since $\bigcap_k X_k$ is in $X_n$ for all $n$, $\bigcap_k X_k \cap F_n = \varnothing$ for all $n$. Since we assume $X = \bigcup_n F_n$, we have
$$ \bigcap _k X_k = \varnothing.$$

Comment: But that's not what we get. If we were to continue the process, we would get $X_2 \cap F_2 = \varnothing$, $X_3 \cap F_{n_2} = \varnothing$, and so on, and not $X_3 \cap F_3 = \varnothing$

Comment: okay. So it seems that we have different continuation of the process in mind. To me $n_k$ is used only to ensure that $X_n$ are non-empty. Can you add the induction step of the construction in your post? @IshanDeo

Comment: @IshanDeo: I’m with **Arctic Char**: if the hint went one step further, the next step would be to observe that $X_2$ meets some $F_{n_3}$ with $n_3>n_2$, to let $U_3$ be an open set containing $F_{n_3}$ whose closure is disjoint from $F_3$, and to let $X_3$ be a component of $X_2\cap\operatorname{cl}U_3$ meeting $F_{n_3}$.

Comment: I've written down the whole hint that was given. And, from the clarification provided by @BrianM.Scott, I realize I misunderstood the induction process that the book was hinting towards. Thanks for clearing that up!

Comment: @IshanDeo: My pleasure!